# Употребление точки. "Загружено с телефона. 2008(.)"

Tags: пунктуация

В группе (социальной сети) опубликованы мои фото с моей же припиской "Загружено с телефона. 2008". Требуется ли после 2008 ставить точку? Пока её там нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если это название, то точка в конце не нужна. Более того, я бы написал через запятую: *"загружено с телефона, 2008".* Но не хочу навязывать — это дело вкуса, тут нет строгого правила.